# how to break long constraints in optidef

Tags: optidef

I am trying to write a optimization problem using optidef package. One of the constraint is too long and I am trying to break it into two lines, however, the only option that I have is using \breakObjective command. the problem is after using \breakObjective, it will write (s.t.) as follow:

[image]

is there anyway that I can get rid of the second (s.t.)?

Thanks.

```
   \usepackage[short]{optidef}
 \begin{mini!}[3]
   {P_{G_i},P_{C_i},P_{D_i}}{ \sum_{m = k}^{k+M} \Bigg( \sum_{\forall i \in N_g} c_G^i ( P_{G_i}[m]-P_{G_i}^r[m] )^2  }
    {\label{eq:optVPP}}{J^*=}
    \breakObjective{\qquad +  \sum_{\forall i \in N_{B}} c_C^iP_{C_i} +        c_D^iP_{D_i} + \sum_{\forall ij \in \mathcal{E}} c_T^{ij}\Delta \hat{T}_{ij}}[m]    \Bigg) \nonumber 
    \addConstraint \sum_{n \in \Omega_i^D} {P_{D_n}[m] + \sum_{n \in      \Omega_i^B} P_{B_n}[m] + \sum_{j \in \Omega_i^N}p_{ij}[m] }\breakObjective{=      \sum_{n \in \Omega_i^G}P_{G_n}[m] 
    \label{eq:const2}}
    \addConstraint{P_{B_n}[m] }{ =P_{C_n}[m]-P_{D_n}[m] \label{eq:const4}}
       \addConstraint{ \underline{P_{G_n}}\leq P_{G_n}[m]}{ \leq      \overline{P_{G_n}} \label{eq:const5}}
 \end{mini!}
```

Comment: At a minimum, you need to provide a complete, minimum working example, that reproduces the problem.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks, I added the code to make it easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mahraz Very important is add a full minimum working example and not a simple fragment.